# A quick way to change one letter when handling objects

Tags: c#, object, shortcut, public

I've tried looking for a solution, but being very new I don't even know where to start.

In  public partial class I need to make 26 lines of code that look like that of below but the C part of ObjC will change from A~Z. Is there a way to do this effectively without copy&pasting the lines again and changing every C there is for 26 times?
I know I could take the time to do this (copy&paste 26 times) but I also have the feeling that there must be a better way to get around.

```
public int[] dn_objC= new int[30]; 
public float[] dtime_objC = new float[30]; 
public float[] ddtime_objC = new float[30];
public int[] dx_objC = new int[30];
public int[] dy_objC = new int[30];
public float[] dxm_objC = new float[30];
public float[] dym_objC = new float[30];
public float[] dsm_objC = new float[30];
public float[] dvx_objC = new float[30];
public float[] dvy_objC = new float[30];
public float[] dv_objC = new float[30];
```

There is no problem with the code right now, I just want to know a quick way to change the C to say A, B, D, etc.

Comment: Use [multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

Comment: Are you are talking about the editor or about code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean the editor. If Visual Studio has a solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: I meant to VS editor, maybe with a macro.. but you didn't mean it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first improvement would be to use [multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) and/or dictionaries.

But it would be even better if you create a custom class first to hold all the data:

```
public class ObjectData {
    public int dn { get; set; }
    public float dtime { get; set; }
    public float ddtime  { get; set; }
    public int dx { get; set; }
    public int dy { get; set; }
    public float dxm { get; set; }
    public float dym { get; set; }
    public float dsm { get; set; }
    public float dvx { get; set; }
    public float dvy { get; set; }
    public float dv { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var objects = new Dictionary<char, ObjectData[]>();
objects['A'] = new ObjectData[30];
...
```

To get or set a specific value, you could do the following:

```
objects['A'][0] = new ObjectData(); // note that you have to instantiate the object first!
objects['A'][0].dn = 14;
Console.WriteLine(objects['A'][0].dn);
```

For further flexibility, use `List`s instead of arrays.

Comment: what do you mean by instantiating the object?

Comment: Unlike value types (`int`, `float`, `bool`) which are by default set to 0 (or false), objects have a default value of `null`. You can't use them until you create an instance, with the [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) keyword.

Comment: Okay. I don't know where to put 
var objects = new Dictionary<char, ObjectData[]>();
objects['A'] = new ObjectData[30];
nor
objects['A'][0] = new ObjectData(); // note that you have to instantiate the object first!
objects['A'][0].dn = 14;
Console.WriteLine(objects['A'][0].dn);

When I put them where the former code was an error occurs. I have made a separate class for the first block of code.

Comment: It depends on where you need them. Typically, the `objects` would be a field of the class, and you can instantiate it as part of the declaration. The rest of the code comes where you are actually initializing the data.

Comment: I have moved the code and now 

`private void end_mes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var objects = new Dictionary<char, ObjectData[]>();
            objects['A'] = new ObjectData[30];
            objects['A'][0] = new ObjectData();
            objects['A'][0].dn = 14;
            Console.WriteLine(objects['A'][0].dn);

            物体Ａ.Text="物体Ａ";
            物体Ｂ.Text = "物体Ｂ";
            flag_object = 0;
            now_status.Text = "測定モード終了";
            MessageBox.Show(dx_objA[1].ToString());
        }`

still dx_objA does not exist in the current context, why?

Comment: I forgot to say that you have to get rid of all the arrays like `dn_objC`. The new construction is not an 'alias' for the old variables.

Comment: So now what should i write instead of `dx_objA` ? I got rid of old the arrays and yet it still shows it does not exist it this context. I've tried other possible ones such as `dx` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `objects['A'][0].dx` - but its value will be 0.

Comment: If I wanted to change `dtime_objB[i]` to `objects['B'][0].dx` where would the [i] go?

Comment: That would be `objects['B'][i].dtime`.

Comment: Will i have to write
`var objects = new Dictionary<char, ObjectData[]>();
                    objects['A'] = new ObjectData[30];`
In every method?

Comment: No - instead of `var objects`, declare `objects` outside the method as `private Dictionary<char, ObjectData[]> objects`. But, honestly, not to be rude, follow some more tutorials on C# application development. These are basic principles which are really hard to explain in comments. And StackOverflow is not the place for them - we solve bugs in code, we don't tell you how to build an application.